# How to place Tabs inside Popover

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6, ionic-tabs, ionic-popover

I am having the requirement where the app is having tab view. The fourth tab is having popover and that popover contains more 3 menus which should act as a tab means it should open like other 3 tabs.

[image]

I have tried but the page is not displaying as it is not setting the popover page as root page inside tab view.

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs #myTab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="theme-business"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="theme-table"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="theme-like"></ion-tab>  
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="presentPopover($event)" tabIcon="ios-apps-outline"></ion-tab>    
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.ts

```
 presentPopover(event) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(TabPopoverPage, {});
    popover.present({ ev: { target: event.btn._elementRef.nativeElement } });
  }
```

tabPopover.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item (click)="openPage('SalonDetailsPage')">
      <ion-icon name="theme-profile" item-left></ion-icon>
      Profile Page
    </button>
    <button ion-item (click)="openPage('SalesReportPage')">
      <ion-icon name="theme-wallet" item-left></ion-icon>
      Sales Report
    </button>
    <button ion-item (click)="openPage('SettingsPage')">
      <ion-icon name="theme-setting" item-left></ion-icon>
      Setting
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

tabPopover.ts

```
openPage(pageName: any) {
    // this.navCtrl.setRoot(pageName);    
    this.navCtrl.push(pageName);
  }
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, you need to update your question with your Code shows what you have implemented. i assume that you have set your routes?

Comment: @SeunBincom: Please check the updated the post.

Comment: this seems to be an ionic 3 app. are you building an ionic 3 or an ionic 4 app?

Comment: There is a limitation to this approach as `ionSelect` event is only emitted when the inactive tab becomes active, however in your case you would want to show popover even when the last tab is already selected.

Comment: @SeunBincom: Its a ionic v4 app.

Comment: @rmalviya:Can you please help to suggest some approach to achieve the same?
Any link or plnkr or explanation would be very grateful.

Comment: @KunalKakkad you are going about setting your navigation wrong sir. navigation in ionic 3 and ionic 4 are completely different. please try to read this article https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-tabs-layout-with-angular-routing-and-ionic-4/

Comment: @SeunBincom: Oh my bad. I was not aware with the same. I am using ionic v3.
Can you please help me out with this to achieve my problem's solution.

Comment: @KunalKakkad no problem. I'll be sharing how to implement this in v3 shortly

Comment: @SeunBincom: Sure. Thanks for it man. Waiting for the same.

Comment: @KunalKakkad Hey, Here is the working implementation of what you need. it's not the best but it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v3-custom-tabs?file=pages/settings/settings.ts

Comment: I think it will work.
As it is working perfect as per the expectations so will implement in real and let you know.
And again thanks a lot for it. You saved my day.

Comment: @SeunBincom Also please answer above url as a part of reply to the post and not as comment so that I can mark it as working so that it would be helpful for others in future.

Comment: @KunalKakkad alright done. Hope this works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186082/discussion-between-kunal-kakkad-and-seunbincom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please Note, while this implementation is not the best and there are probably a dozen other ways to solve this problem, this was the easiest. 
>   you can find a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v3-custom-tabs

*there may be a way to Programmatically add a new ion-tab item but i could not locate that on the ionic docs but here is my take of the implementation based on this question*

### Step 1:

we currently have 4 tab items, we add the extra tab items we need.

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" show= "false"  tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" show= "false" tabIcon="cash"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab6Root" show= "false" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
```

**NOTE the show attribute**
show: according to ionic docs hides the tab element . https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/#input-properties
this creates the ion-tab elements but hides them.

### step 2:

we need a reference to the ion-tabs element which was already define with `<ion-tabs #myTab>`

**page: tabs.ts**

// we are getting the ion-tabs using the template reference then assigning it to a local variable `tabRef`

`@ViewChild('myTab') tabRef: Tabs;`

```
presentPopover(event) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {navpage: this}); // note the navpage: this
    popover.present({ ev: { target: event.btn._elementRef.nativeElement } });

  }
```

we need a way to reference this component (TabsPage), so we are passing it as a nav params
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/#create
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/#get

### step 3:

***page: popover.html***

```
<button ion-item (click)="openPage(4)">
  <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
  Profile Page
</button>
<button ion-item (click)="openPage(5)">
  <ion-icon name="cash" item-left></ion-icon>
  Sales Report
</button>
<button ion-item (click)="openPage(6)">
  <ion-icon name="settings" item-left></ion-icon>
  Setting
</button>
```

// each of the number represent the tab index of the page we wish to navigate to see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#selecting-a-tab

***page: PopoverPage***

```
// the tabs page ref
tabsPageRef: TabsPage;

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams
    ) {
    // recall the navpage: this from the TabsPage?
      this.tabsPageRef = this.navParams.get('navpage');
  }


  openPage(pageName: any) {
    // here, we are using the reference of the TabsPage to access the local variable tabref
    this.tabsPageRef.tabRef.select(pageName)
  }
```